# Where are the launcher shortcuts stored in Ubuntu Netbook?

Tags: 10.10, ubuntu-netbook, launcher

The thing on the left is called a launcher right?

Anyway, I want to apply a few applications with custom arguments, namely

> google-chrome --user-agent "That of iPad's"

Possible?

Oh, and how would I utilise all that free desktop space that UNR doesn't want me to use? Way to much space there - why can't I put desktop icons there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to `System=>Preferences=>Main Menu` and select the category (internet) and then your app (Google Chrome), click on the `properties` button and add extra options to the *command*